# Tuning linux filesystem caching for aggressive writing to block storage

Tags: linux, filesystems, amazon-web-services

I have an Amazon EC2 instance of type `c4.8xlarge` that I'm using as a target for ongoing rsync processes that are storing my database data files and transaction logs for disaster recovery purposes.  The EC2 instance doesn't have any workload besides receiving files from rsync.  I'm using EBS volumes to store the files (one per database instance), and after rsync finishes, I'm taking an EBS snapshot of the volume.

I was initially surprised to find that my snapshots contained partially written files, even after my rsync process had finished cleanly.  I eventually figured out that the data was in the filesystem cache, and since EBS snapshots happen at the block level, anything that was in memory but not written to disk yet was of course not in the snapshot. Calling an explicit `/bin/sync` before my snapshot resulted in consistent snapshots.

However, `/bin/sync` sometimes takes a REALLY long time (IMO) to finish.  It's very common for it to take 5-10 minutes, and sometimes as much as 15 minutes.  However, I have multiple rsync jobs running, and if one of them has called `/bin/sync` recently, then of course a subsequent invocation is very fast (less than a second).  I'm looking to smooth this out, so that the system writes changes to the block storage more frequently.  The goal is to improve overall write performance and have more predictable and consistent durations of my rsync jobs.

My question is:  **how can I tune the filesystem cache such that when rsync is reading/comparing files to calculate the transfer delta, it uses available RAM aggressively, but also writes dirty blocks to disk aggressively?**  I've read up on the kernel parameters in `/proc/sys/vm` but most of the documentation I've been able to find seems to assume I'm either an experienced linux sysadmin (I'm not really, I'm a DBA that does sysadmin tasks out of necessity) or that I can comfortably read the kernel source code (I can't).

I believe these are the relevant parameters from `/sbin/sysctl`.  I have not set any of these intentionally:

```
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 10
vm.dirty_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
vm.dirty_ratio = 20
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500
vm.dirtytime_expire_seconds = 43200
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 100
```

Comment: What filesystem type are you running?

Comment: I'm running xfs.